# Angular google maps error:- Uncaught Error: Google Maps API not available

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-google-maps

I am new in Ionic app development. I installed angular google maps using bower

```
bower install angularjs-google-maps
```

then added these ref files in index.html

```
<script src="lib/lodash/dist/lodash.js"></script>
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-simple-logger/dist/angular-simple-logger.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB52Z0xUP6JEX9fjr1EEQvCWgo8W4DD5CY&extension=.js"></script>

<script src="lib/angularjs-google-maps/dist/angularjs-google-maps.js"></script>
```

Finally added the gm module as a dependency to your AngularJS app:

```
angular.module('taskerApp', ['ionic', 'taskerApp.controllers', 'taskerApp.services', 'pickadate', 'gm'])
```

It is showing a blank screen and giving this error in console.

```
angularjs-google-maps.js:40 Uncaught Error: Google Maps API not available, please make sure the Google Maps library is loaded before the AngularJS Google Maps library is loaded
```

Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs:

> Make sure to load the AngularJS library and the Google Maps API:
>
> ```
> <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
> <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
> ```
>
> Then load the AngularJS Google Maps library:
>
> ```
> <script src="bower/angularjs-google-maps/dist/angularjs-google-maps.js"></script>
> ```
>
> Finally add the gm module as a dependency to your AngularJS app:
>
> ```
> angular.module('yourApp', ['gm']);
> ```
>
> That's it! You can now start adding Google Maps directives to your
>   markup.

My guess is you don’t include the files in the right order.

Comment: Order as you can see is same as shown here but it helped me as a copy pasted "<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
"  the problem causing the error was missing "libraries=places" in url